# assignment discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type - When trying to retrieve a value

Tags: c, couchbase

Couchbase uses an event-based model. So in order to retrieve values I have to set up a call-back handler and then throw a get-request at the database. It is done like this:

```
[... some stuff happens]
/* set up a callback for our get requests  */
lcb_set_get_callback(instance, get_callback);
```

In the `get_callback` I have a `cookie` to put my values into. So I parse the object I get back and put it into the cookie via:

```
json_t *object;

[... some error handling and parsing]

/*Put the json_object into the cookie*/
lcb_set_cookie(instance, object);
```

When I want to retrieve it I have to use `lcb_get_cookie` [man page](https://github.com/couchbase/libcouchbase/blob/b818254182127fae4d9dbf0400de0fd284fbaa8e/man/man3couchbase/lcb_get_cookie.3couchbase.txt) which returns a void pointer but says: "lcb_get_cookie() returns the value set by lcb_set_cookie(), or NULL if
no value is set by lcb_set_cookie()." So I want to do something like:

```
/* Retrieve the ad out of the cookie*/
ad_json = lcb_get_cookie(instance);
```

When I try to use it like this I get a warning:
`warning: assignment discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [enabled by default]`. So I'm confused. How can I retrieve the value I put into the cookie?

**Edit:**
I forgot to mention that I need to further process the data and want to make changes to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tell compiler that you promise not to change that cookie:

```
json_t const * object = lcb_get_cookie(instance);
```

But if you need to change it, you could perhaps cast it, because manual says that *"...libcouchbase will not do
anything with the value."*:

```
json_t * object = (json_t *)lcb_get_cookie(instance);
```

But maybe safer alternative would be to copy the contents to a new cookie, make changes and set it again?

I don't know the exact layout of `json_t`, by if it does not contain any internal pointers, simple assignment might do the trick:

```
 json_t const * old = lcb_get_cookie(instance);
 json_t * new = /* init pointer with your new object */;
 *new = *old; /* Copy data */
```

Comment: That's the thing. I want to make changes to it. I forgot to mention it and will edit my question.

Comment: I like the idea of copying it. How would I go about doing it? My grasp of C is still very rudimental. - Thank you for your quick and thorough help good sir!